# Numbering several equations with one number

Tags: latex

I used this code to number these equations with only one number but it display the equations right aligned. In this case, how can I align them centered?

```
\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:41}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{df_0}{d\eta} = f_1\\
        \frac{df_1}{d\eta} = f_2\\
        \frac{df_2}{d\eta} = f_3\\
        \frac{df_3}{d\eta} = \frac{1}{\lambda f} \Bigg(\Bigg.f_3+f_0 f_2 - f_1 ^2+\lambda \left(2f_1 f_3 - f_2 ^2 \right) -Mf_1 -Pf_1 + Gr_T \theta_0 + Gr_C\phi_0 \Bigg. \Bigg)   
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

I expect the equations to be center aligned and referenced by only one number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \label{eq:41}
    \begin{gathered}
        \frac{df_0}{d\eta} = f_1\\
        \frac{df_1}{d\eta} = f_2\\
        \frac{df_2}{d\eta} = f_3\\
        \frac{df_3}{d\eta} = \frac{1}{\lambda f} \Bigg(\Bigg.f_3+f_0 f_2 - f_1 ^2+\lambda \left(2f_1 f_3 - f_2 ^2 \right) -Mf_1 -Pf_1 + Gr_T \theta_0 + Gr_C\phi_0 \Bigg. \Bigg)   
    \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]